# MyBatis ... Get Last insert ID in loop "foreach"

Tags: mybatis

Thank you for help :)

I tried to get last id, and read many post about it, but i don't arrive to apply it in my case.

**First Class**

```
private Date date;
private List<AdsEntity> adsDetails;

    ... getters and setters
```

**Second Class** (AdsEntity)

```
private int id;
private String description;
```

There is the code where i try to get the last id :

**Mapper**

```
@Insert({
    "<script>",
    "INSERT INTO tb_ads_details  (idMyInfo, adDate)"
    + " VALUES"
        + " <foreach item='adsDetails' index='index' collection='adsDetails' separator=',' statement='SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()' keyProperty='id' order='AFTER' resultType='java.lang.Integer'>"
            + " (#{adsDetails.description, jdbcType=INTEGER}) "
        + " </foreach>  ",  
    "</script>"})
void saveAdsDetails(@Param("adsDetails") List<AdsDetailsEntity> adsDetails);
```

In debugging mode, when I watch List I see the id still at 0 and don't get any id.

So what I wrote didn't workout :(

---

**Solution Tried with the answer from @Roman Konoval :**

@Roman Konoval

I apply what you said, and the table is fully well set :)
Just one problem still, the ID is not fulfill

```
    @Insert("INSERT INTO tb_ads_details SET `idMyInfo` = #{adsDetail.idMyInfo, jdbcType=INTEGER}, `adDate` = #{adsDetail.adDate, jdbcType=DATE}")
    @SelectKey(statement = "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()", before = false, keyColumn = "id", keyProperty = "id", resultType = Integer.class )
    void saveAdsDetails(@Param("adsDetail") AdsDetailsEntity adsDetail);


    default void saveManyAdsDetails(@Param("adsDetails") List<AdsDetailsEntity> adsDetails)
    {
        for(AdsDetailsEntity adsDetail:adsDetails) {
            saveAdsDetails(adsDetail);
        }
    }
```

[image]

Thank for your help :)

---

**Solution add to @Roman Konoval proposal from @Chris advice**

@Chris and @Roman Konoval

```
    @Insert("INSERT INTO tb_ads_details SET `idMyInfo` = #{adsDetail.idMyInfo, jdbcType=INTEGER}, `adDate` = #{adsDetail.adDate, jdbcType=DATE}")
    @SelectKey(statement = "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()", before = false, keyColumn = "id", keyProperty = "adsDetail.id", resultType = int.class )
    void saveAdsDetails(@Param("adsDetail") AdsDetailsEntity adsDetail);




    default void saveManyAdsDetails(@Param("adsDetails") List<AdsDetailsEntity> adsDetails)
    {
        for(AdsDetailsEntity adsDetail:adsDetails) {
            saveAdsDetails(adsDetail); 
        }
    }
```

[image]

**Thanks to all of you, for the 3 suggestions!!!**

Comment: what is the structure of the `tb_ads_details` that is please provide the definition of the table. And more importantly how id for records in it are generated?

Comment: **Wrote by** @Chris :            currently im unable to check it by myself. sorry. you used the ```@Param``` annotation. its possible that you also have to use the parametername for keyPropertylike ```keyProperty = "adsDetail.id"```. you could also try to remove ```@Param``` annotation and adsDetail.from your insert statement - like this: ```#{idMyInfo, jdbcType=INTEGER}``` – Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Chris wrote about inability to get ids in the `foreach` is correct. However there is a way to implement id fetching in mapper without the need to do it externally. This may be helpful if you use say spring and don't have a separate DAO layer and your mybatis mappers are the Repository.

You can use [default interface method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html) (see [another tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java8/java8_default_methods.htm) about them) to insert the list of items by invoking a mapper method for single item insert and single item insert method does the id selection itself:

```
interface ItemMapper {
  @Insert({"insert into myitem (item_column1, item_column2, ...)"})
  @SelectKey(before = false, keyColumn = "ID", 
     keyProperty = "id", resultType = Integer.class, 
     statement = { "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()" } )
  void saveItem(@Param("item") Item item);

  default void saveItems(@Param("items") List<Item> items) {
    for(Item item:items) {
      saveItem(item);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Roman Konoval.  I'm new in programming as you can see. I have difficulty to understand your coding part "default void saveItems ... " Can you please, give some explanation about it ? Thanks so so much !! :)

Comment: Re Hello @Roman Konoval   I still have one problem with the ID. I've show to you in an answer post i did at your attention :)     Thanks for your help

Comment: @RomanKonoval thank you for your answer. i added this to my "example-project" to keep that in mind :)

Answer (score 2):

yes. it doesnt work.

please take a look at [mapper.dtd](http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd)

`foreach`-tag doesnt support/provide the following properties `statement`, `keyProperty` `order` and `resultType`

if you need the id for each inserted item please let your `DataAccessObject` handle iteration and use something like this in your MapperInterface

```
@Insert("INSERT INTO tb_ads_details (idMyInfo, adDate) (#{adsDetail.idMyInfo, jdbcType=INTEGER}, #{adsDetail.adDate, jdbcType=DATE})")
@SelectKey(before = false, keyColumn = "ID", keyProperty = "id", resultType = Integer.class, statement = { "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()" } )
void saveAdsDetails(@Param("adsDetail") AdsDetailsEntity adsDetail);
```

please ensure `AdsDetailsEntity`-`Class` provides the properties `idMyInfo`and `adDate`

**Edit 2019-08-21 07:25**

**some explanation**

referring to the mentioned dtd the `<selectKey>`-tag is only allowed as direct child of `<insert>` and `<update>`. it refers to a single `Object` that is passed into the mapper-method and declared as `parameterType`.

its only executed once and its `order` property tells myBatis wether to execute it before or after the insert/update statement.

in your case, the `<script>` creates one single statement that is send to and handled by the database.

it is allowed to combine `@Insert` with `<script>` and `<foreach>` inside and `@SelectKey`. but myBatis doesnt intercept/observe/watch database handling the given statement. and as mentioned before, `@SelectKey` gets executed only once, before or after `@Insert`-execution. so in your particular case `@SelectKey` returns the id of the very last inserted element. if your script inserts ten elements, only the new generated id of tenth element will be returned. but `@SelectKey` requires a class-property with getter and setter to put the selected id into - which `List<?>` doesnt provide.

**example**

lets say you want to save an `Advertisement` and its `AdvertisementDetail`s

`Advertisement` has an id, a date and details

```
public class Advertisement {
    private List<AdvertisementDetail> adDetails;
    private Date date;
    private int id;

    public Advertisement() {
        super();
    }

    // getters and setters
}
```

`AdvertisementDetail` has its own id, a description and an id the `Advertisement`it belongs to

```
public class AdvertisementDetail {
    private String description;
    private int id;
    private int idAdvertisement;

    public AdvertisementDetail() {
        super();
    }

    // getters and setters
}
```

the MyBatis-mapper could look like this. `@Param` is not used, so the properties are accessed direct.

```
@Mapper
public interface AdvertisementMapper {
    @Insert("INSERT INTO tb_ads (date) (#{date, jdbcType=DATE})")
    @SelectKey(
            before = false,
            keyColumn = "ID",
            keyProperty = "id",
            resultType = Integer.class,
            statement = { "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()" })
    void insertAdvertisement(
            Advertisement ad);

    @Insert("INSERT INTO tb_ads_details (idAdvertisement, description) (#{idAdvertisement, jdbcType=INTEGER}, #{description, jdbcType=VARCHAR})")
    @SelectKey(
            before = false,
            keyColumn = "ID",
            keyProperty = "id",
            resultType = Integer.class,
            statement = { "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()" })
    void insertAdvertisementDetail(
            AdvertisementDetail adDetail);
}
```

the `DataAccessObject` (DAO) could look like this

```
@Component
public class DAOAdvertisement {
    @Autowired
    private SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory;

    public DAOAdvertisement() {
        super();
    }

    public void save(
            final Advertisement advertisement) {
        try (SqlSession session = this.sqlSessionFactory.openSession(false)) {
            final AdvertisementMapper mapper = session.getMapper(AdvertisementMapper.class);
            // insert the advertisement (if you have to)
            // its new generated id is received via @SelectKey
            mapper.insertAdvertisement(advertisement);
            for (final AdvertisementDetail adDetail : advertisement.getAdDetails()) {
                // set new generated advertisement-id
                adDetail.setIdAdvertisement(advertisement.getId());
                // insert adDetail
                // its new generated id is received via @SelectKey
                mapper.insertAdvertisementDetail(adDetail);
            }
            session.commit();
        } catch (final PersistenceException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.     Well I wrote this line incorrectly it's ```(#{adsDetails.decription, jdbcType=String})``` to be correct with adsEntity Class.    In any case If i do like your example I will lose the "foreach" statement and List<AdsDetailsEntity>. And that's not really what I want :(

Comment: I've correct the code I wrote. Like this you will understand better :)

Comment: It's a relation One to Many        The first class to many AdsEntity (Second class)

Comment: I tried to write this in the code:    ```<selectKey keyProperty='id' order='AFTER' resultType='java.lang.Integer'> SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() </selectkey```      But it doesn't work too. Or maybe where I wrote it, was at an incorrect place.

Comment: Well if i understood correctly @Chris, what you are saying, when you use annotation, MyBatis, for he's philosophy,  doesn't want we use "foreach" in the mapper, but in the DAO ? is it correct ?

Answer (score 1):

MyBatis can assign generated keys to the list parameter *if* your DB/driver supports multiple generated keys via `java.sql.Statement#getGeneratedKeys()` (MS SQL Server, for example, [does not support it](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-jdbc/issues/245), ATM).

The following example is tested with MySQL 5.7.27 + Connector/J 8.0.17 (you should include version info in the question).
Be sure to use the latest version of MyBatis (=3.5.2) as there have been several spec changes and bug fixes recently.

Table definition:

```sql
CREATE TABLE le tb_ads_details (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  description VARCHAR(32)
)
```

POJO:

```java
private class AdsDetailsEntity {
  private int id;
  private String description;
  // getters/setters
}
```

Mapper method:

```java
@Insert({
  "<script>",
  "INSERT INTO tb_ads_details (description) VALUES",
  "<foreach item='detail' collection='adsDetails' separator=','>",
  "  (#{detail.description})",
  "</foreach>",
  "</script>"
})
@Options(useGeneratedKeys = true, keyProperty="adsDetails.id", keyColumn="id")
void saveAdsDetails(@Param("adsDetails") List<AdsDetailsEntity> adsDetails);
```

Note: You should use batch insert (with `ExecutorType.BATCH`) instead of multi-row insert (=`<foreach/>`) when inserting a lot of rows.

Comment: **It works very well !!!! Thanks @ave**     I would like also do it with the solution of @Roman Konoval that is another very good approach too :)   I hope he will still help to found out :)

Comment: @ave thank you too, for your answer, i also added this to my "example-project" to keep that in mind. i didnt know about the `@Options` annotation. :)